# VBA code weekend date on name and specific folder and automatic saving

Tags: vba, format

I need help to modify this VBA code to save the pdf in a specific folder and with a weekend date witch i calculated basicaly in a cell called E 24 Or if its another way. Can someoane help please ?

```
Private Sub Picture2_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Range("E24").value.Format, "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
    If Dir(v) <> "C:\Users\user\Desktop\work invoices" Then
        If MsgBox("File already exists - do you wish to overwrite it?", vbYesNo, "File Exists") = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        With ActiveSheet
            .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=v, _
                                 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=3, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "accounts@email.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Job number 1868"
            .Body = ""
            .Attachments.Add v
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What do you need help with, specifically? Please take a few moments to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question.

Comment: What isn't working with the code above and what is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result:

Comment: Expected result:
Save active sheet as a PDF in specific folder with Sunday date as a name, then attach and send it to specific email address.